Unity Shadergraph Add node isn’t doing what is expected
I am currently setting up a shadergraph which has two different alpha effects being applied, however when I individually pass them to the alpha channel it is fine and they work as expected but when I add them together in the Add node and pass it to the alpha channel suddenly neither of the effects work. It’s as if they’re overriding each other or something. I’ve tried multiplying them together and that doesn’t seem to work so is there some other node you’re supposed to use when combining together two values into one?

Let me know if there’s more information needed
